# Will I get the Splunk hat when a [data] tag is added to a question after I answered it?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

... and will it be seen as "cheating" when I add such a tag afterwards by myself, maybe after my answer already got an upvote? (Of course, the tag should fit to the question's content.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, during the time when I asked this question, I could see I got the Splunk hat awarded for a question where I made the experiment to add a [data] tag afterwards. So it is definitely possible to earn the hat that way. I don't think it is seen as cheating when askers add the tag by themselves, I can also add such a tag when simply asking a question and tagging it accordingly, so it is definitely expected to get the hat by one's own actions alone (let alone the necessary upvote from someone else).

Comment: Hats are notorious for having triggers that encourage bad behavior on SE. This seems a perfect example of that. Adding the tag to a question where it isn't relevant just to trigger a hat maybe isn't 'cheating', but it's definitely also not a good behavior/use of the system. Tags should reflect the content of a post, and edits should be used to improve the post, not for getting hats. So even though this works, don't do it, behave yourself and keep the sites neat and clean.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: I thought I already made clear in my question that the tag should fit to the content, of course. And for the particular case, I added a datastructure tag to a question which I formerly answered, where I noticed that it was about datastructures, but the OP missed to use the specific tag. Still I am wondering what happens one one adds a data tag somewhere which does not fit, earns the hat and then removes the tag again.

Answer (score 0):

Since whether a given tag can be added is debated, it might be regarded as cheating.

On the other hand, would someone not upvote a question or answer on the grounds it had an inaccurate tag?  That's the only reason why adding the tag would make a difference.

Comment: "would someone not upvote a question or answer on the grounds it had an inaccurate tag" - only questions have tags, so votes on the ground of tags rarely go to answers.

Comment: @DocBrown Nevertheless the question was whether it would be cheating if the tag were added afterwards so it's about that case.